# vertical align not working

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

is it possible to vertically align an image coming inside an anchor tag ?

I am using two anchor tags inside a DIV.. each one should vertically align to center.
in one  I am using an image in another one text ?

PS: without line-height

Answer (score 11):

Vertical align does not behave as you'd think in divs since it works only for table cells.

There are numbers of CSS "hacks" to get that to work such as [this one](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) or [this one](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-vertical-align.html)

Comment: this answer is OBSOLETE...it works with inline objects and inline-block, but it needs to be set on the object itself and not on it's parent. and also then, it will not always work...

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't vertical align inside a div tag but you can with a table cell. You could work around it if you can fix the height of your image and its container.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
/* Internet Explorer 10 */
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;

/* Firefox */
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
display:box;
box-pack:center;
box-align:center;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple using CSS.

Here's an example:

```
#anySection {
    background: white url(../images/anyImage.jpg) no-repeat center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="anySection"></div>
```

You'll get a 500 x 500 px section with your image centered inside.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This works for me:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    div.parent {
         position: relative;
    }

    /*vertical middle and horizontal center align*/
    img.child {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="parent">
        <img class="child"> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Least hacky solution that works for me. altough not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the following url, it may hold the answers you need as well as give you a comprehensive understanding of the vertical align property.

http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody's pointed it out, you get different behaviours depending on the DOCTYPE.

(In my case, the transitional doctype wasn't vertically aligning inline elements without sibling text nodes, whereas html5 does.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;height:200px;position: relative;">
     <div style="position: absolute;top: 50%;left:50%;">
     hello mahesh // Div Body part
     </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0dmh3ac3/)

Try this.